# Woocommerce: how to update an order programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Currently, my customers fill out a form which takes their measurements and then recommends a product variation specifically for their measurements. This is great, but takes time and is not always convenient for the customer.

I want to allow my customers to purchase a generic version of the product (so they pay immediately), submit their measurements at a later, more convenient date for them (e.g. through a form they fill out) and then update the purchased product to a specific variation with their measurements.

Is it possible to do this in Woocommerce? If so, how could I do this programmatically?

Comment: Ofc you can. Depending on the way you gonna process orders may need different approach. In the basic what i would do is create my products as i want. Customer select a product (may need restriction one per order) there are no available payment methods except a simple one that just places the order. After that customer can access his order there you gonna have your form and at submit update the order.

Comment: Ofc if customer fills the fields on checkout you can dynamicly show payment methods